# How to put my text on the right and left side from the image to vertical center?

Tags: css, html

I have to put the text on the left and right side from my Image to the vertical center. But it seems that my containsers wouldn't know which height they have.

How can i fix this?

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 vert">
        <p>
          Text 1
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" style="height: 60px" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
        Text 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: in addition read this article about flex-boxes :) https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your footer is `60px` add `line-height:60px` like this:

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  
}

.vert {
  line-height:60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 vert">
        <p>
          Text 1
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" style="height: 60px" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-right vert">
        Text 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: @DominicBürki You're welcome. Remember to mark an answer as correct (whatever you prefer).

Answer (score 1):

Just add align-items: center; to your .row and remove the p tag from the first .col-md-4 or add it to the second one.

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 vert">
        <p>
          Text 1
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" style="height: 60px" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
        Text 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
align-items: center;
```

this will center your content vertically.